# Why is it advisable to use String.isEmpty() to check String is empty or not over String.length() method?

Tags: java, string

I got a coding review comment about my use  of `String.length()` to see whether String is equal to `""` ie contains no char or not.

I was using `String.length()==0` in my code.

I didn't understand why `String.isEmpty()` is recommended is it because of performance reason or some other reason?

Comment: both works the same, it is just a matter of convention of your team + with isEmpty() there is no chance you will type length() == 1 (which is close to 0 on keyboard)

Comment: They give you a method to do exactly what you want; might as well use it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both represent the same information, but `String#isEmpty` improve the readability of the code...

consider this snippet:

```
String foo = "";
if (foo.isEmpty()) {
    // TODO
}
if (foo.length() == 0) {
    // TODO
}
```

the intention of isEmpty is less ambiguous than the length check....
further modications on the code will be easier to do, furthermore we normally  dont do

```
foo.length() == 0    //because 0 is a magic number
```

but

```
foo.length() == SOME_CONSTANT
```

same criteria is used aswell with collections, wher you will see

```
if(myList.isEmpty())
```

instead of

```
if(myList.size() == 0)
```

Answer (score 2):

There is no *inherent* difference between the two, but you should probably rely on `string.isEmpty();` rather than `string.length() == 0` for these reasons:

- It's smaller, takes up less space.
- It looks cleaner, objectively.
- If something changes inside of Java that changes how String emptiness is checked, you get that update without having to change over to the new system.

A general rule of thumb: if you are provided a method to do something, use that method rather than using your own.

Answer (score 0):

As per oracle java api https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#isEmpty--

public boolean isEmpty()

Returns true if, and only if, length() is 0.
Returns:true if length() is 0, otherwise false

There is no difference.

Answer (score 0):

There's nothing wrong with using either of the two methods - `isEmpty` and `length`. They both achieve the same objective. If you look at the [source code](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/8u40-b25/java/lang/String.java?av=f) of these two methods in the `String` class, you will see the following:

```
public int length() {
    return value.length;
}

public boolean isEmpty() {
     return value.length == 0;
}
```

As you can see, they both refer to an internal variable `value` which is defined as a character array.

```
private final char value[];
```

So you can use either of these two methods to check for empty strings. One may argue that `isEmpty` has a better readability than `length`.

Don't forget to do a null check before calling any of these two methods.

Answer (score 0):

Internally in `String` class `isEmpty` implemented this way

```
public boolean isEmpty() {
    return value.length == 0;
}
```

So, no any difference instead of readability.

However, often you also need to check if string variable equals `null` or not (case 1). Or if string variable contains only spaces (case 2). In this case is better to use Apache Commons utility methods:

for case 1: [StringUtils#isEmpty](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/apidocs/org/apache/commons/lang3/StringUtils.html#isEmpty-java.lang.CharSequence-)

for case 2: [StringUtils#isBlank](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/apidocs/org/apache/commons/lang3/StringUtils.html#isBlank-java.lang.CharSequence-)